# Same site to be hosted on multiple port in IIS

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7.5

I have one website which is running on 443 port on a particular DNS (https://mypage.com:443/login).
Now, I want to redirect the same to a new site (mynewsite.com:443). I have done using redirect option in the sites in IIS where I have given redirect URL as https://mynewsite.com:443. All the requests which are coming to https://mypage.com:443/login is successfully getting redirected to https://mynewsite.com:443

Now, I have another DNS (https://mysecondDNS:443). I want that users who are accessing this https://mysecondDNS:443 should be redirected to https://mypage.com:443/login ONLY.

But the users who are directly accessing https://mypage.com:443/login should go into https://mynewsite.com:443

Can this be achieved in IIS.

What I have tried till now is, I have another site with port 8080/8081 and tried for redirecting, but that does not seems to be working.

Can some one pls help me or guide me how to achieve this.

thanks

Comment: I tried to achieve your need but failed. I think it is impossible to achieve that. When the requested URL meets the redirection rules, IIS will rewrite the URL. IIS cannot distinguish whether the request is a direct request from the user or a redirected request. What IIS can do is if the rewritten URL still meets a certain rule, it can prevent the URL from being rewritten again.

Comment: thanks. As an alternative, can it be a working solution in this way.
Create another site to run on different port (may be 9443) with same application. So, now, the application would load in two different ports. For one of the port, it can be redirected to new website and for one port there is no redirection.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to redirect `mysecond` to `mypage`, and direct access to `mypage` to `mynewsite`. If `mypage/login` is also a page that exists on IIS, it should not be used as a redirect URL. The purpose of URL rewriting is to rewrite or redirect friendly URLs to complex URLs, which are not easy for users to remember. If you create a new site to run the `mypage/login` page, you can achieve it. `mysecond` can be redirected to a port that can no longer be redirected, and another port will be redirected to `mynewsite`.

Comment: I want to move this because, for few set of users the older website is still needed. But for majority of the users (except few set) would be there with new website. So in order to make the few users access this older site, I want to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution to your problem, and it is feasible after testing. You can add custom headers during the rewriting process.

In my test, I created three sites corresponding to your three domain names, `mynewsite.com  myscondDNS.com  and mypage.com`. They all have their own pages.

When users visit `mysecondDNS.com`, they will be redirected to `mypage.com`. According to your description, the page of `mypage.com` should be displayed. Only when users directly visit `mypage.com` will request be redirected to `mynewsite.com`.

In order to facilitate the URL rewrite module to recognize the request, when `mysecondDNS.com` redirected to `mypage.com`, I added a custom header **HTTP_REQ_from**(the header must be start with **HTTP_**) and assigned the value ***mysecondDNS*** to it. When `mypage.com` is redirected to `mynewsite.com`, the header will be judged. If the header value matches, the request will not be redirected, and will be redirected to mynewsite.com if it does not.

This is rule to add custom header

```
<rule name="rule">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://mypage.com" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_REQ_from" value="mysecondDNS" />
                </serverVariables>
 </rule>
```

This is rule to judge custom header

```
<rule name="rule">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_REQ_from}" pattern="mysecondDNS" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://mynewsite.com" />
            </rule>
```

Log in failed request tracing, mysecondDNS to mypage, will not redirect to mynewsite
[image]

[image]

mypage redirect to mynewsite(the request send by user, no HTTP_REQ_from in header)
[image]

Comment: thanks. Can this be achieved by IIS configuration?

Comment: Yes, all these can be configured on URL rewrite module.